# Can one define null value serialization policy in JAXB/MOXy for entire class or globally in the mapping file?

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I only found a way to define null handling policy per individual property:

```
<xml-element java-attribute="something">
    <xml-null-policy xsi-nil-represents-null="false" empty-node-represents-null="false" null-representation-for-xml="EMPTY_NODE" is-set-performed-for-absent-node="true" />
</xml-element>
```

Is there a way to define it globally in the mapping file at the xml-bindings level or at least at the java-type level?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

We currently don't have a mechanism to globally default the null representation.  There is an existing enhancement request for this feature.  If you have a chance please vote for this bug as it will move it up our priority list.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/368547